# Intramolecular or intermolecular?

Tags: electronegativity

I am extremely confused about these types of forces.

Some websites state that the forces in the covalent bonds of carbon dioxide are inter. Other websites say they are intra?

Also, some websites say that the electrostatic bond between ionic compounds is intra, others say they are inter.

So, which is inter and which is intra?

Comment: Hey Daniel, welcome to Chem.SE! Can you please cite those websites, which state these things, so we too can have a look?

Answer (score 3):

Inter- means in between molecules (like the interstate highway - in between states)and intra- means within one molecule ( like an intrastate highway- within one state). So a covalent bond of CO2 OR an electrostatic ionic bond would be an intramolecular bond. The type of bond that keeps water molecules close to each other ( hydrogen bonding) is an example of an intermolecular attraction.